# Self-contained, STL-compatible implementation of std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, alignment

The implementation of `std::vector` that ships with Visual Studio 2010 and earlier versions has a well known particularity: the `resize` method has the following signature (C++03-compliant):

```
void resize(size_type new_size, value_type value);
```

instead of the C++11-compliant signature that's been used by the majority of other STL implementations (like gcc's STL or STLport) long before C++11:

```
void resize(size_type new_size, const value_type& value);
```

The problem with the first variant is that, in some situations, it will fail to compile if `value_type` has an alignment specification:

```
struct __declspec(align(64)) S { ... };
std::vector<S> v;  // error C2719: '_Val': formal parameter with __declspec(align('64')) won't be aligned
```

This is a [well](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/stdvector-of-aligned-elements/) [known](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/stdvector-of-aligned-elements-revisited/) problem with no satisfactory workaround apart from using a different implementation of `std::vector`.

**I'm looking for a well-written, well-tested, self-contained and STL-compatible implementation of `std::vector` with a MIT-style licence** that I could drop into my project as a container of choice for aligned types.

I considered extracting it from STLport or gcc's STL but, being fully standard-compliant, they're both large with many non-trivial dependencies.

(I would be perfectly happy with an implementation of a reasonable subset of `std::vector` that would only support `push_back`, `clear`, `capacity`, `size`, `reserve`, `resize`, `swap` and array indexing.)

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see how the `.resize()` method causes the `std::vector<S> v;` declaration to fail. Instantiating a class template does not instantiate its methods, only those used. (I.e. default ctor and dtor in this case).

Comment: I guess the error is emitted during parsing... Keep in mind we're talking about a truly compiler-specific issue here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The guys behind the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) library seem to have found a nice workaround for the problem of storing "overly-aligned types" ([as Stephan T. Lavavej call them](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/721286/vc-std-vector-does-not-support-data-alignment)) into a `std::vector` as implemented in Visual Studio's STL.

Their implementation seems unnecessary complicated (check the sources [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/69228ecab94b/Eigen/src/StlSupport/details.h) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/69228ecab94b/Eigen/src/StlSupport/StdVector.h)) but the main idea is to encapsulate the type that goes into the `std::vector` with a thin wrapper:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct wrapper : public T
{
    wrapper() {}
    wrapper(const T& rhs) : T(rhs) {}
};

struct __declspec(align(64)) S
{
    float x, y, z, w;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< wrapper<S> > v;  // OK, no C2719 error
    return 0;
}
```

About the implementation in Eigen, I must admit I don't quite understand

- why they need `Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection`,
- why they need to make an exception for arithmetic types in `EIGEN_WORKAROUND_MSVC_STL_SUPPORT`,
- why they need to define all these constructors and operators in `Eigen::workaround_msvc_stl_support`,
- or why they need to redefine `resize` in their partial specialization of `std::vector` for the `Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection` allocator...

Clues welcome. The point is, this trick works perfectly (as far as I can tell) and I don't see anything wrong with it, apart maybe from the slight inelegance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and best, imho) option would be to provide a free function as an extension to the `vector` interface, which does the right thing. The functions you need to implement `resize` are all available from the public interface of `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

template<class T, class Alloc>
void resize(std::vector<T, Alloc>& v,
    typename std::vector<T, Alloc>::size_type new_size, T const& val)
{
  if (v.size() < new_size)
      v.insert(v.end(), new_size - v.size(), val);
  else if (new_size < v.size())
      v.erase(v.begin() + new_size, v.end());
}
```

And for consistency also the single argument version:

```
template<class T, class Alloc>
void resize(std::vector<T, Alloc>& v,
    typename std::vector<T, Alloc>::size_type new_size)
{
    v.resize(new_size); // simply forward
}
```

If you, however, just want to drop-in the new vector and never worry about free or member function, another option is to simply subclass `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class myvector
  : public std::vector<T, Alloc>
{
  typedef std::vector<T, Alloc> base;
public:
  typedef typename base::size_type size_type;

  void resize(size_type new_size){
    base::resize(new_size);
  }

  void resize(size_type new_size, T const& val){
    if (this->size() < new_size)
        this->insert(this->end(), new_size - this->size(), val);
    else if (new_size < this->size())
        this->erase(this->begin() + new_size, this->end());
  }
};
```

Note that I also provided the single argument version of `resize`, since the two argument version would hide all base-class versions. Also note that I needed to prefix all member function calls with `this->`, since they are dependent on the base class `std::vector`, and as such on the template arguments.

Comment: Subclassing `std::vector` was one of my first approach, unfortunately it still fails to compile because in the end, `std::vector` still gets instantiated.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune: Ah, that's relatively unfortunate. :/ Try commenting out the `std::vector` version, or simply fix the signature. :P FWIW, VS11 still doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: Strange, according to STL [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/721286/vc-std-vector-does-not-support-data-alignment), `vector::resize` in VS11 should have the `T const&` signature, but the current developer preview doesn't... I think I'll drop him a mail.