# Using std::atomic with aligned classes

Tags: c++, c++11, sse

I have a `mat4` class, a 4x4 matrix that uses sse intrinsics.  This class is aligned using `_MM_ALIGN16`, because it stores the matrix as a set of `__m128`'s.  The problem is, when I declare an `atomic<mat4>`, my compiler yells at me:

```
f:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\atomic(504): error C2719: '_Val': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
```

This is the same error I get when I try to pass any class aligned with `_MM_ALIGN16` as an argument for a function (without using `const &`).

How can I declare an atomic version of my mat4 class?

Comment: I believe the C++ standard only says that "support for overaligned types is implementation defined"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSC compiler has never supported more than 4 bytes of alignment for parameters on the x86 stack, and there is no workaround.

You can verify this yourself by compiling,

```
struct A { __declspec(align(4)) int x; }; 
void foo(A a) {}
```

versus,

```
// won't compile, alignment guarantee can't be fulfilled
struct A { __declspec(align(8)) int x; };
```

versus,

```
// __m128d is naturally aligned, again - won't compile
struct A { __m128d x; };
```

Generally MSC is absolved by the following,

> You cannot specify alignment for function parameters.
>
> [align (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And you cannot specify the alignment, because MSC writers wanted to reserve the freedom to decide on the alignment,

> The x86 compiler uses a different method for aligning the stack. By
>   default, the stack is 4-byte aligned. Although this is space
>   efficient, you can see that there are some data types that need to be
>   8-byte aligned, and that, in order to get good performance, 16-byte
>   alignment is sometimes needed. The compiler can determine, on some
>   occasions, that dynamic 8-byte stack alignment would be
>   beneficial—notably when there are double values on the stack.
>
> The compiler does this in two ways. First, the compiler can use
>   link-time code generation (LTCG), when specified by the user at
>   compile and link time, to generate the call-tree for the complete
>   program. With this, it can determine regions of the call-tree where
>   8-byte stack alignment would be beneficial, and it determines
>   call-sites where the dynamic stack alignment gets the best payoff. The
>   second way is used when the function has doubles on the stack, but,
>   for whatever reason, has not yet been 8-byte aligned. The compiler
>   applies a heuristic (which improves with each iteration of the
>   compiler) to determine whether the function should be dynamically
>   8-byte aligned.
>
> [Windows Data Alignment on IPF, x86, and x64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Thus as long as you use MSC with the 32-bit platform toolset, this issue is unavoidable.

The x64 ABI has been explicit about the alignment, defining that non-trivial structures or structures over certain sizes are passed as a pointer parameter. This is elaborated in [Section 3.2.3 of the ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf), and MSC had to implement this to be compatible with the ABI.

**Path 1: Use another Windows compiler toolchain: GCC or ICC.**

**Path 2: Move to a 64-bit platform MSC toolset**

**Path 3: Reduce your use cases to `std::atomic<T>` with `T=__m128d`, because it will be possible to skip the stack and pass the variable in an XMM register directly.**

Comment: Right now, as a workaround, I'm using an std::mutex to protect access to the mat4 (which is non-"atomic").  Is there a better way?

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach Yes locking the data to protect access is the official (POSIX) way to treat the topic. On Windows you can also look into the Interlocked family of operations, eg InterlockedExchangePointer, but this is not applicable if you want to keep working with value types on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

The `atomic<T>` probably has a constructor which is passed a copy of `T` as a [(formal) parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870156/what-is-a-formal-parameter). For example in the `atomic` header packaged with GCC 4.5 :

```
97: atomic(_Tp __i) : _M_i(__i) { }
```

This is problematic for exactly the same reason as any other function which has a memory aligned type as a parameter: It would be very complicated and slow for functions to keep track of memory aligned data on the stack.

Even if the compiler allowed it, this approach would [incur a significant performance penalty](http://demin.ws/blog/english/2012/05/05/atomic-spinlock-mutex/). Assuming you are trying to optimise for speed I would implement a less fine grained memory access approach. Either locking access to a chunk of memory whilst performing a series of calculations, or explicitly designing your program so that threads never try and access the same piece of memory.

Comment: How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem using [Agner Fog's vectorclass](http://www.agner.org/optimize/vectorclass.zip) in MSVC.  The problem happens in 32-bit mode.  If you compile in 64-bit mode release mode I don't think you will have this problem.  In Windows and Unix all variables on the stack are aligned to 16 bytes in 64-bit mode but not necessarily in 32-bit mode.  In his manual under compile time errors he writes

> "error C2719: formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned".
>   The Microsoft compiler cannot handle vectors as function parameters. The
>   easiest solution is to change the parameter to a const reference, e.g.:
>   Vec4f my_function(Vec4f const & x) {
>   ... }

So if you use a const reference (as you mentioned) when you pass your class to a function it should work in 32-bit mode as well.

Edit: Based on this [Self-contained, STL-compatible implementation of std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409591/self-contained-stl-compatible-implementation-of-stdvector/9414618#9414618)  I think you can use a "thin wrapper".  Something like.

```
template <typename T>
struct wrapper : public T
{
    wrapper() {}
    wrapper(const T& rhs) : T(rhs) {}
};

struct __declspec(align(64)) mat4
{
    //float x, y, z, w;
};

int main()
{
    atomic< wrapper<mat4> > m;  // OK, no C2719 error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried using the thin wrapper, but I'm still getting the exact same errors.  I can't change microsoft's implementation of std::atomic, so passing by a const reference wont work either.  I would rather not force 64-bit mode...

Answer (score 0):

I don't profess to understand how `__declspec(align(foo))` is supposed to work, but [this standard C++ program compiles and runs fine in gcc & clang using `alignas(16)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb410b1bc06dc016):

```
struct alignas(16) mat4 {
    float some_floats[4][4];
};

std::atomic<mat4> am4;
static_assert(alignof(decltype(am4)) == 16,
              "Jabberwocky is killing user.");

int main() {
    static const mat4 foo = {{
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    }};
    am4 = foo;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I guess it doesn't work in visual studio (or else it works with structs, but not classes).